# ES6 "Import()" issues "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" [Webpack - NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules

I transpile my ES6 code using Webpack along with BabelJS in NodeJS environment. The problem is that, when I try to import a set of specific `.js` modules, the `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` exception would be thrown. This is the main chunk of code I've written so far:

```
export default async () => {
  const modulesToBeImportedByNames = ['a.js', 'b.js', 'c.js'];
  const modulesToBeImportedByPromises = 
      modulesToBeImportedByNames.map(moduleFilename => 
        import(`./${moduleFilename}`) // exception is thrown here
      );
  const importedModules = await Promise.all(modulesToBeImportedByPromises);
}
```

Note: I've used `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` plugin within my BabelJS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the filenames should be relative, as you are importing application files.

```
const modulesToBeImportedByNames = ['./a.js', './b.js', './c.js'];
```